# Get min value in row during LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

*I know that I can use .Min() to get minimum value from column, but how to get minimum value in a row?*

I have following LINQ query (for testing purposes):

```
from p in Pravidloes
where p.DulezitostId == 3
where p.ZpozdeniId == 1 || p.ZpozdeniId == 2
where p.SpolehlivostId == 2 || p.SpolehlivostId == 3

group p by p.VysledekId into g
select new {
  result = g.Key,
  value = g
}
```

Which results into this:
[image: linqqueryimage]

I would however like to get only the **MIN value of following** three columns:
**DulezitostId, ZpozdeniId, SpolehlivostId** as a value in:

```
select new {
  result = g.Key,
  value = g // <-- here
}
```

The final result then should look like:
result: 2, value: 1
result: 3, value: 2

I have been looking for similar questions here and googled for few examples with grouping and aggregating queries, but found nothing that would move me forward with this problem.

Btw: Solution isn't limited to linq, if you know better way how to do it.

Comment: Not many Czechs around here, it's good to see another one.

Comment: Hi.. Yea, indeed. Btw: thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an array of the values and do Min on those.

```
select new {
  result = g.Key,
  value = g.SelectMany(x => new int[] { x.DulezitostId, x.ZpozdeniId, x.SpolehlivostId }).Min()
}
```

This will return the min for those 3 values in each grouping for ALL rows of that grouping.

Which would result in something like this...

result: 3, value: 1

The below will select the min for each row in the grouping...

```
select new {
  result = g.Key,
  value = g.Select(x => new int[] { x.DulezitostId, x.ZpozdeniId, x.SpolehlivostId }.Min())
}
```

Which would result in something like this...

result: 3, value: 1, 2

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to do it almost like this, but didn't know the correct syntax. Anyway.. I am getting this error: `Constructed arrays are only supported for Contains.`

Comment: @Dampe: LINQ to SQL doesn't know how to translate that query into SQL. Call `AsEnumerable()` on the part before this select and then you can do this select on the result in memory.

Comment: @Dampe see my answer -- if you're using Linq To Sql you can use Math.Min instead

Comment: Correct with LINQ to SQL you either have to force the query (.ToArray(), .ToList()) and then do it or use Math.Min(Math.Min(x1, x2), x3)

Comment: Ok, that did the job. I guess that I should have mentioned I am working with entity framework context (ie. LINQ to Entities I guess?). Thanks again. I was fighting with it at least for an hour :)

Answer (score 3):

The best solution if you're using straight LINQ is [Chad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747526/get-min-value-in-row-during-linq-query/5747594#5747594).  However, if you're using Linq To SQL it won't work because you can't construct an array like that.

Unfortunately, I believe the only way to do this in Linq To Sql is to use Math.Min repeatedly:

```
select new {
  result = g.Key,
  value = Math.Min(Math.Min(DulezitostId, ZpozdeniId), SpolehlivostId)
}
```

This will generate some ugly `CASE WHEN ...` statements, but it works.

The main advantage of doing it this way is that you're only returning the data you need from SQL (instead of returning all 3 columns and doing the `Min` in the application).

Comment: +1, Thanks for your input. This is also a valuable answer, but I have decided to use the first solution for my case. (Unfortunatelly can't mark both answers :) )

Comment: @Dampe the other answer is nicer code, but be aware that if you're selecting a lot of rows, doing the MIN in memory instead of SQL requires pulling 3x as much data across the network from the DB.

Comment: Right now, I am getting exactly 4 rows. And in future, I don't count with more than 10, so it should be ok I guess.

Comment: @Dampe ah yes, then this is not a concern for you :)